# Scheduled Job in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created job in sql i want the procedure should execute at particular time on everyday. 
I know it is not so difficult but my SQL is in sharing Environment so how can fix the schedule..

I have created sample procedure my procedure will be similar to this....

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[INSERTMULTIPLE]
   AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @ID INT, @RAVINDER VARCHAR(100), @MONTY VARCHAR(100),@DINESH         
   VARCHAR(100),@ANKIT VARCHAR(100)
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
   (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    RAVINDER VARCHAR(100),
    MONTY VARCHAR(100),
    DINESH VARCHAR(100),
    ANKIT VARCHAR(100)
    )
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE(RAVINDER,MONTY,DINESH,ANKIT) SELECT 
    R.NAME,M.NAME,D.NAME,A.NAME FROM RAVINDER R 
    INNER JOIN MONTY M ON R.ID=M.RID 
    INNER JOIN DINESH D ON M.ID=D.MID 
    INNER JOIN ANKIT A ON D.ID=A.DID
    END
    DECLARE @pK INT
    DECLARE @maxPK int

    set @pK = 1
    SELECT @maxPK = COUNT(*) FROM #TEMPTABLE

    WHILE (@pK<=@maxPK )
    BEGIN
    select @ID = ID from #TEMPTABLE where ID=@pK
    SELECT @RAVINDER = RAVINDER FROM #TEMPTABLE WHERE ID=@pK
    SELECT @MONTY = MONTY FROM #TEMPTABLE WHERE ID=@pK
    SELECT @DINESH = DINESH FROM #TEMPTABLE WHERE ID=@pK
    SELECT @ANKIT = ANKIT FROM #TEMPTABLE WHERE ID=@pK

    if(@pK<=@maxPK)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO INSERTALL(RAVINDER,MONTY,DINESH,ANKIT 
    )VALUES(@RAVINDER,@MONTY,@DINESH,@ANKIT)
    END
    SET @pK=@pK+1
    END
    END
```

Comment: Ask your sharing provider how to use/setup SQL Server jobs in his environment ....

Answer (score 0):

Ask your sharing provider. How comes you even consider us knowing how a provider - not even named by you - internall handles that? Ouch.

If that does not work, forget about it. Schedule OUTSIDE - i.e. from your website or another app - and call the SP once per day at the desired time. Pretty much the better way anyway in terms of knowing what goes on. There are a number of web cron services out there that can call a URL at a specified time.